# How do I add Widgets to a Column through code

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add widgets to a Column dynamically. The following approach does not work as the button does not add the text widgets when clicked. I'd like to understand why this doesn't work and what should I do to make it work. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> c = [];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Column(children: [
        Column(children: c),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          print("testing");
          c.add(Text("testing"));
        }, child: Text("Add Text"))
      ])
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: I edited my code to be in a stateful widget and added a setState function around the function that adds the widgets to the container, but it still won't work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class SW extends StatefulWidget {
  const SW({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SWState createState() => _SWState();
}
class _SWState extends State<SW> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> c = [];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Column(children: [
        Column(children: c),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            print("testing");
            c.add(Text("testing"));
          });
        },
        child: Text("Add Text"))
      ])
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SW();
  }
}



void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyState createState() => _MyState();
}

class _MyState extends State<MyApp> {

  List<Widget> c = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Column(children: [
        Column(children: c),
        ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
          setState((){
print("testing");
          c.add(Text("testing"));
});
        }, child: Text("Add Text"))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrap your on pressed code in setstate to rebuild the page. The setState function triggers rebuild of the whole widget tree shown in your screen. And without that the text widget will only be added to the list but won't be shown to the screen.

Comment: I tried to add setState but it didn't recognize the function, so I read further about it and realised I can only use it on stateful widgets. So I edited my code and now it does recognize setState, but it still doesn't add new widgets

Comment: Have updated the code and tested it. Try this now

Comment: Okay! It works now, that's great! But why did my edited code not work? Is it because MyApp itself isn't a stateful widget?

Comment: No, You need to place the material app widget in the void main or outside this stateful widget. If you found this useful and then pls accept the answer.